# Analyze and generate code for whole Spring Boot Maven project

Tags: java, maven, javaparser

I am trying to accomplish code generation and analysis of my entire Spring Boot Maven application.

What I want to achieve is just like IDEA analyzes the whole project and find dependencies for a class in the editor. For example, if a class is using:

```
class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringUtils.rpad(...)
    }
}
```

If I click on StringUtils it takes me to the source code of the class in Spring jar that is included by the Maven.

In similar fashion, I would like the JavaParser to analyze the whole project and build some kind of index or whatever that IDEA creates. And then I can discover all the related jars and class files. That will allow me to manipulate / refactor some classes.

I tried to do similar thing for Eclipse AST/JDT. Unfortunately, this is only possible if I create an Eclipse plugin, in that case Eclipse plugin creates a project which have the idea of the whole project and its dependencies.

In my case I don't want to create Eclipse or IDEA plugin. The reason is that I want to create some kind of script / tool that can be run from command line. So I need standalone support from a code generator like JavaParser.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Not yet. But there is a thing called Symbol parser or something like that which looks relevant. You can explore and update me. I would do the same once time permits.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse the pom file and get all the dependencies.
2. Get path of the dependencies and add the jar file to a type resolver
3. Set the static type resolver
4. Parse using the static type resolver.

**Keep in mind** This could be simplified, this is to load in a whole spring boot project using the artifact information and the pom file, this info you can also extract out of the pom file.

This example uses a class named Project to include all needed fields for a spring boot project

**Method to extract the dependencies**

```
public static List<Dependency> parseDependencies(Project project) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    final var result = new ArrayList<Dependency>();
    Model model = readModel(project.getPomFile());
    List<org.apache.maven.model.Dependency> dependencies = model.getDependencies();
    for (org.apache.maven.model.Dependency dependency : dependencies) {
        final var dep = new Dependency();
        dep.setGroup(dependency.getGroupId());
        dep.setArtifact(dependency.getArtifactId());
        dep.setVersion(dependency.getVersion());
        dep.setProject(project);
        result.add(dep);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Usage**

```
CombinedTypeSolver typeSolver = new CombinedTypeSolver(
        new ReflectionTypeSolver()
);
parseDependencies(this).forEach(dependency -> {
    if(dependency.getVersion() == null){
        final var versions = new java.io.File(artifactDir).listFiles();
        if(versions == null || versions.length == 0){
            throw new RuntimeException("No versions found for dependency: " + dependency.getArtifact());
        }
        dependency.setVersion(Arrays.stream(versions).map(java.io.File::getName).max(String::compareTo).orElseThrow());
    }
    final var jar = new java.io.File(artifactDir + "/" + dependency.getVersion() + "/" + dependency.getArtifact() + "-" + dependency.getVersion() + ".jar");
    if(!jar.exists()){
        throw new RuntimeException("Dependency not found: " +     jar.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    try {
        typeSolver.add(new JarTypeSolver(jar));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
JavaSymbolSolver symbolSolver = new JavaSymbolSolver(typeSolver);

StaticJavaParser
        .getParserConfiguration()
        .setSymbolResolver(symbolSolver);
final var pack = getGroup() + "." + getArtifact().replaceAll("-", "").toLowerCase();
final var rootDir = new java.io.File(projectLocation + "/src/main/java/" + pack.replace(".", "/"));
if(!rootDir.exists()){
    throw new RuntimeException("Root directory does not exist: " + rootDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
if(rootDir.listFiles() == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("Root directory is empty: " + rootDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
final var mainJava = Arrays.stream(rootDir.listFiles()).filter(file -> file.getName().endsWith(".java")).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No main class found"));
CompilationUnit compilationUnit = StaticJavaParser.parse(mainJava);
```